# TextChanged event triggering again when I make a postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, updatepanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="uppBaixa" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="txt1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txt2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This is basically what the ASPX looks like. When I leave (tab) `txt1` the `TextChanged` event is called and it normally fills `txt2`. But when I change the text in `txt2`and hit `btnSave`to update this data, the `txt1_TextChanged` is called AGAIN (before the actual `btnSave_Click` method triggers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you

- Take your sample UpdatePanel and put it into a new project (and add the ScriptManager)
- Add the following methods

  ```
  protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      this.txt1.Text = "foo";

  }
  protected void txt1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      txt2.Text = txt1.Text;
  }
  ```
- Update txt1 to ABC then txt2 will become ABC
- Update txt2 to Bar then txt1.Text will be ABC and txt2 will Bar
- Pressing Save will just change txt1 to Foo and txt will remain Bar

This means that what you've described doesn't reproduce.

Note that even when you set `txt1.text = "foo"` on server side it doesn't raise the `textChanged` event, which means its probably something on the client side

Try adding this to your `Page_Load` event to find it.

```
  this.btnSave.Attributes.Add("OnClick", "debugger");
```

Comment: Sorry for that. The code is working (at least the part i've mentioned), I just don't have it here to put it all.. I tried posting this "pseudo" code here and see if someone had this kind of problem